# ArrayObject::getIterator error

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, get

This is how i am trying to get some apartments name from the database, but i am always getting er error. This is how i am trying to get the apartments names

```
$userapt = $user->getApartments()->getIterator();

while ($userapt->valid()) {
  echo  ($userapt->key() . ' => ' . $userapt->current()) . "\n";

    $userapt->next();
}

$useraptName = $user->getApartment()->getIterator();

while ($useraptName->valid()) {
    ($useraptName->key() . ' => ' . var_dump($useraptName->current()) . "\n");
    $useraptName->next();
}
```

Running this, I get following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class MyBundle\Entity\UserApartment could not be converted to string
>   500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

How can this error be fixed?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `echo` an object

`echo  ($userapt->key() . ' => ' . $userapt->current()) . "\n";`

you can solve this by implementing the `public function __toString() {}` method in the `UserApartament` class. In this way when you will try to `echo $user->current()` it will use the `__toString()` method to show the string value of your object.

Comment: Why not solve the root of the problem - and just not to try `echo` the object? It's kinda weird.

Comment: @zerkms I don't know the real needs, but in some way you are right, usually you don't have to echo objects...

Comment: For any needs it's weird: how you output is context-specific. You just cannot have a single implementation that fits all suits.